# Regexs for finding text inside and outside javascript strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am searching for text inside of website resources (html and javascript), and need to identify 3 regular expressions that will locate this text under certain circumstances:

1. some string of text when it is contained inside of a javascript single-quoted string
2. some string of text when it is contained inside of a javascript double-quoted string
3. some string of text when it is not contained inside of a javascript string

Here are some scenarios that are likely to occur (searching for the string "somestring"):

```
document.write("here is a bunch of text and somestring is inside of it");
var thing = 'here is a bunch of text and somestring is inside of it';
document.write("some text and 'quote' and then somestring here");
document.write('some text and "quote" and then somestring here');
var thing = "some text and '" + quotedVar + "' and then somestring here");
document.write('some text and "' + quotedVar + '" and then ' + " more " + "somestring here");
this string is outside javascript and here is a 'quoted' line and somestring is after it
this string is outside javascript and here is a "quoted" line and somestring is after it
```

These examples might all appear inside the same file, and so the regular expressions should not assume single-case scenarios.

I have tried the following for finding single-quoted and double-quoted strings, but alas I have failed miserably:

single quotes:

```
([=|(|\+]\s*?'[^']*?(?:'[^']*?'[^']*?)*?somestring)
```

double quotes:

```
([=|(|\+]\s*?"[^"]*?(?:"[^"]*?"[^"]*?)*?somestring)
```

These work when assuming the right conditions, but there are many real-world scenarios that I have tried (read, real javascript files) where they fail.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** For clarification, I am looking for 3 regular expression for each of the conditions listed above, not one that covers all cases.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this with regular expressions if you really have to handle general-case source files.

Comment: Can you expand further pointy as to why not? What do you recommend then?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to locate somestring no matter where it appears - within javascript or outside it. Why don't you just look for somestring? Or do you actually need to be able to tell which of the three scnearios it is?

Comment: It's because the source text that you're attempting to parse is constructed with grammars that cannot be parsed by regular expressions. It's just one of those things; a regular expression can only deal with a certain class of grammar.

Comment: Elad, it's mandatory that I know which of the 3 scenarios the text was located, I need to know if the text was contained in single quotes, double quotes, or neither.

Comment: Pointy is right.  This touches on the same principles involved in the famous "parsing html with regex debate"... http://danielmiessler.com/blog/stack-overflows-answer-to-can-you-parse-html-with-regex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags (for reference to "the debate")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Be careful what you ask for!

The first two of your three objectives can be done fairly well using regex, but it is not trivial and is not 100% reliable - (see caveats below).

### Picking strings out of JavaScript

First lets look at how to pick out single and double quoted sub-strings from a longer string of purely Javascript code (not HTML). Note that to do this correctly, a regex must not only match both types of quoted strings, it must also match both single and multi-line comments. This is because quotes may appear inside comments (e.g. `/* I can't take it! */`), and these quotes must be ignored. Also, comment delimiters may appear inside quoted strings (e.g. `var str = "This: /* can cause trouble too!";`), so all four constructs must be parsed out in one pass. Here is a regex which matches both types of comments and both types of quoted strings. It is presented in commented, verbose mode (using PHP single quoted syntax):

```php
$re = '%# Parse comments and quoted strings from javascript code.
      /\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^*/][^*]*\*+)*/             # A multi-line comment, or
    | (\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\S\s][^\'\\\\]*)*\')  # $1: Single quoted string, or
    | ("[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\S\s][^"\\\\]*)*")      # $2: Double quoted string, or
    | //.*                                       # A single line comment.
    %x';
```

This regex captures single quoted strings into group `$1` and double quoted strings into group `$2`, (and either type of string may contain escaped characters, e.g. `'That\'s cool!'`). Both types of comments are captured by the overall match when neither the `$1` or `$2` capture groups match. Note also, that this regex implements Jeffrey Friedl's *"unrolling-the-loop"* efficiency technique (See: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)), so it is quite fast.

**`process_js()`**
The following Javascript function: `process_js()`, implements the above regex (in non-verbose, native Javascript RegExp literal syntax). It performs a global (repetitive) replace using an anonymous function which processes the single and double quoted strings independently, and preserves all comments. Two additional functions: `process_sq()` and `process_dq()` perform the processing on the matched single and double quoted strings respectively:

```js
function process_js(text) { 
    // Process single and double quoted strings outside comments.
    var re = /\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^*\/][^*]*\*+)*\/|('[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*')|("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*")|\/\/.*/g;
    return text.replace(re,
        function(m0, m1, m2){
            if (m1) return process_sq(m1);  // 'single-quoted'.
            if (m2) return process_dq(m2);  // "double-quoted".
            return m0;                      // preserve comments.
        });
}
function process_sq(text) {
    return text.replace(/\bsomestring\b/g, 'SOMESTRING_SQ');
}
function process_dq(text) {
    return text.replace(/\bsomestring\b/g, 'SOMESTRING_DQ');
}
```

Note that the two quoted-string handling functions merely replace the keyword: `somestring` with `SOMESTRING_SQ` and `SOMESTRING_DQ`, so that the results of the processing will be evident. These functions are designed to be modified by the user as-needed. Lets see how this performs with a string of Javascript (similar to the example provided in the OP):

**Test data input:**

```js
// comment with  foo somestring bar  in it
// comment with "foo somestring bar" in it
// comment with 'foo somestring bar' in it
/* comment with  foo somestring bar  in it */
/* comment with "foo somestring bar" in it */
/* comment with 'foo somestring bar' in it */

document.write(" with  foo somestring bar  in it ");
document.write(' with  foo somestring bar  in it ');
document.write(' with "foo somestring bar" in it ');
document.write(" with 'foo somestring bar' in it ");

var str = " with  foo somestring bar  in it ";
var str = ' with  foo somestring bar  in it ';
var str = ' with "foo somestring bar" in it ';
var str = " with 'foo somestring bar' in it ";
```

**Test data output from `process_js()` :**

```js
// comment with  foo somestring bar  in it
// comment with "foo somestring bar" in it
// comment with 'foo somestring bar' in it
/* comment with  foo somestring bar  in it */
/* comment with "foo somestring bar" in it */
/* comment with 'foo somestring bar' in it */

document.write(" with  foo SOMESTRING_DQ bar  in it ");
document.write(' with  foo SOMESTRING_SQ bar  in it ');
document.write(' with "foo SOMESTRING_SQ bar" in it ');
document.write(" with 'foo SOMESTRING_DQ bar' in it ");

var str = " with  foo SOMESTRING_DQ bar  in it ";
var str = ' with  foo SOMESTRING_SQ bar  in it ';
var str = ' with "foo SOMESTRING_SQ bar" in it ';
var str = " with 'foo SOMESTRING_DQ bar' in it ";
```

Notice that `somestring` has been processed only within valid Javascript strings and has been ignored within comments. For pure Javascript, this function works *pretty darn good!*

### Picking Javascript out of HTML

Parsing Javascript from HTML using regex is not recommended (see caveats below). However, a reasonably good job can be done if you are comfortable using a complex regex, and are happy with its limitations (once again, see caveats below). That said, here are the requirements for our regex solution: In HTML, Javascript can occur inside `<SCRIPT>` elements, and within `onclick` event tag attributes (and all the other HTML 4.01 events: `ondblclick`, `onmousedown`, `onmouseup`, `onmouseover`, `onmousemove`, `onmouseout`, `onkeypress`, `onkeydown` and `onkeyup`). Javascript can also occur within `javascript:`-pseudo-URLs, but IMHO, that is *really bad practice*, so this solution does not attempt to match these. HTML is a complex language and our scraping regex needs to ignore comments and `CDATA` sections. A multi-global-alternative regex (similar to the previous one), matches each of these structures. Here is the "pluck-js-from-html" regex in commented, verbose mode (once again presented in PHP single quoted syntax):

```php
$re = '%# (Unreliably) parse out javascript from HTML.
    # Either... Option 1: SCRIPT element.
      (<script\b[^>]*>)         # $1: SCRIPT open tag.
      ([\S\s]*?)                # $2: SCRIPT contents.
      (<\/script\s*>)           # $3: SCRIPT close tag.
    # Or... Options 2 and 3: onclick=quoted-js-code.
    | (                         # $4: onXXXX = 
        \bon                    # All HTML 4.01 events...
        (?:click|dblclick|mousedown|mouseup|mouseover|
           mousemove|mouseout|keypress|keydown|keyup
        )\s*=\s*                # with = and optional ws.
      )                         # End $4:
      (?:                       # value alternatives are either
        "([^"]*)"               #    $5: Double-quoted-js,
      | \'([^\']*)\'            # or $6: Single-quoted-js.
      )                         # End group of alternatives.
    # Or other HTML stuff that we should not mess with.
    | <!--[\S\s]*?-->           # HTML (non-SGML) comment.
    | <!\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\]>  # or CDATA section.
    %ix';
```

In this regex, we capture `SCRIPT` javascript content in groups: `$1` (open tag), `$2` (contents) and `$3` (closing tag) and `onXXX` event handler code in groups: `$4` (event attribute name), `$5` (double-quoted value contents) and `$6` (single-quoted value contents). Comments and `CDATA` sections are captured by the overall match (when none of the capture groups match). Note that this regex does not make use of the "unrolling-the-loop" technique (although it certainly could), because that would add too much complexity for most readers. (All three of the lazy-dot-star expressions i.e. `[\S\s]*?`, can be unrolled to speed this up.)

**`process_html()`**
The following Javascript function: `process_html()`, implements the above regex (in non-verbose, native Javascript RegExp literal syntax). It performs a global (repetitive) replace using an anonymous function which processes the three different sources of javascript code. It then calls the previously described `process_js()` function to process the captured js code. Here it is:

```js
function process_html(text) {
    // Pick out javascript from HTML event attributes and SCRIPT elements.
    var re = /(<script\b[^>]*>)([\S\s]*?)(<\/script\s*>)|(\bon(?:click|dblclick|mousedown|mouseup|mouseover|mousemove|mouseout|keypress|keydown|keyup)\s*=\s*)(?:"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')|<!--[\S\s]*?-->|<!\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\]>/g;
    // Regex to match <script> element
    return text.replace(re,
        function(m0, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6) {
            if (m1) { // Case 1: <script> element.
                m2 = process_js(m2);
                return m1 + m2 + m3;
            }
            if (m4) { // Case 2: onXXX event attribute.
                if (m5) {  // Case 2a: double quoted.
                    m5 = process_js(m5);
                    return m4 + '"' + m5 + '"';
                }
                if (m6) {  // Case 2b: single quoted.
                    m6 = process_js(m6);
                    return m4 + "'" + m6 + "'";
                }
            }
            return m0; // Else return other non-js matches unchanged.
        });
}
```

**Test data input:**

```html
<script>
/* comment with 'foo somestring bar' in it */
document.write(" with 'foo somestring bar' in it ");
var str = " with 'foo somestring bar' in it ";
</script>

<!-- with  foo somestring bar  in it -->
<!-- with "foo somestring bar" in it -->
<!-- with 'foo somestring bar' in it -->

<![CDATA[ with  foo somestring bar  in it ]]>
<![CDATA[ with "foo somestring bar" in it ]]>
<![CDATA[ with 'foo somestring bar' in it ]]>

<p>non-js with  foo somestring bar  in it non-js</p>
<p>non-js with "foo somestring bar" in it non-js</p>
<p>non-js with 'foo somestring bar' in it non-js</p>

<p onclick="with  foo somestring bar  in it">stuff</p>
<p onclick="with 'foo somestring bar' in it">stuff</p>
<p onclick='with  foo somestring bar  in it'>stuff</p>
<p onclick='with "foo somestring bar" in it'>stuff</p>
```

**Test data output from `process_html()` :**

```html
<script>
/* comment with 'foo somestring bar' in it */
document.write(" with 'foo SOMESTRING_DQ bar' in it ");
var str = " with 'foo SOMESTRING_DQ bar' in it ";
</script>

<!-- with  foo somestring bar  in it -->
<!-- with "foo somestring bar" in it -->
<!-- with 'foo somestring bar' in it -->

<![CDATA[ with  foo somestring bar  in it ]]>
<![CDATA[ with "foo somestring bar" in it ]]>
<![CDATA[ with 'foo somestring bar' in it ]]>

<p>non-js with  foo somestring bar  in it non-js</p>
<p>non-js with "foo somestring bar" in it non-js</p>
<p>non-js with 'foo somestring bar' in it non-js</p>

<p onclick="with  foo somestring bar  in it">stuff</p>
<p onclick="with 'foo SOMESTRING_SQ bar' in it">stuff</p>
<p onclick='with  foo somestring bar  in it'>stuff</p>
<p onclick='with "foo SOMESTRING_DQ bar" in it'>stuff</p>
```

As you can see, this works pretty darn good and correctly modifies only quoted strings within javascript within HTML.

**Caveats:** To correctly and reliably extract Javascript from HTML, (i.e. *parse it*) you must use a parser. Although the above algorithm does a pretty decent job, there are certainly cases where it will fail. For example the following non-javascript code will be matched:

```html
<p title="Title with onclick='fake code erroneously matched here!'">stuff</p>
<p title='onclick="alert('> and somestring here too </p><p title=');"'>stuff</p>
<p title='<script>alert("Bad medicine!");</script>'>stuff</p>
```

*Phew!*

Comment: Ridge you are ridiculous! Checking this now but +1 anyway for your awesome regex skills (you answered another regex question of mine previously and it worked).

Answer (score 0):

Consider an initial 'parse' (I use the term loosely) which generates three different resultant streams -- one for each of the search domains.

In this stage just increment-step through the file stopping on the tokens `/`, `'` and `"` as these change the 'context' (possible comment, regex, or string). Then determine (for the `/` case) and consume the context contents and put it into the appropriate resultant stream. (Finding the end is still a little bit tricky in cases like `"foo\"bar\\"`, but much less tricky than a regex trying to match the contexts in a search.)

When this stage is done -- besides being verifiable -- each of the individual streams can be easily searched independently.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Three regular expressions can't correctly handle this in all cases because JavaScript has no regular lexical grammar : it is not possible to always identify whether a quote starts a string.

Even assuming you can correctly identify and ignore quotes inside comments, quotes inside regular expressions will foil you.

For example,

```
x++/y - "42" /i
```

vs

```
x = ++/y - "42"/i
```

In the first case, the quotes are part of a string.  The first sample is the same as

```
((x++) / (y - 42)) / i
```

but in the second case, the quotes are not part of the string.  It is the same as

```
x = ++(new RegExp('y - "42"', 'i'))
```

which is a syntactically valid, but nonsensical JavaScript statement.

If you're willing to ignore comments and weird constructs like this, then you can match strings using

```
/"(?:[^"\\]|\\(?:[^\r]|\r\n?))*"/
```

and

```
/'(?:[^'\\]|\\(?:[^\r]|\r\n?))*'/
```

which will match EcmaScript 5 style strings with line continuations.